# Ubuntu 14.04 Running Low Graphics Mode After Upgrading Software

Tags: nvidia, upgrade

I'm having problem with my PC. It says "System is running in low graphics mode"
I'm using nvidia gt430 graphics card. Everything was ok after installing Ubuntu 14.04 but after installing software updates the error happen, i can no longer use my pc, The last thing i remember the default graphics driver I used was xorg nouvou driver.
Please help me I already reinstalled ubuntu 3times but have the same problem. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please open a terminal (CTRL+Alt+T) and type ` dpkg --list | grep nvidia* ` followed by ENTER. Add the output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is bug at ubuntu 14.04. It not working as the same as older version. When you install Ubuntu, press left shift. Choose your language, press f6, choose pci off. Then esc, than try Ubuntu. You have to try it before install it. In the live image choose to install than it will work.